# Using Moq, how do I set up a method call with an input parameter as an object with expected property values?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, moq

```
 var storageManager = new Mock<IStorageManager>(); 
 storageManager.Setup(e => e.Add(It.IsAny<UserMetaData>()));
```

The Add() method expects a UserMetaData object which has a FirstName property.

I'd like to make sure that an object of type UserMetaData with the FirstName of "FirstName1" has been passed.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can use `Verify`.

**Examples:**

Verify that `Add` was never called with an `UserMetaData` with `FirstName`!= `"FirstName1"`:

```
storageManager.Verify(e => e.Add(It.Is<UserMetaData>(d => d.FirstName!="FirstName1")), Times.Never());
```

Verify that `Add` was called at least once with an `UserMetaData` with `FirstName`== `"FirstName1"`:

```
storageManager.Verify(e => e.Add(It.Is<UserMetaData>(d => d.FirstName=="FirstName1")), Times.AtLeastOnce());
```

Verify that `Add` was called exactly once with `FirstName` == `"Firstname1"` and `LastName` == `"LastName2"`:

```
storageManager.Setup(e => e.Add(It.Is<UserMetaData>(data => data.FirstName == "FirstName1"
                                                         && data.LastName  == "LastName2")));

...

storageManager.VerifyAll();
```

Comment: @FaisalHafeez `VerifyAll()` would be usefull if you don't call `Verify` explicitly, but use `Setup` to specify your expectation.

Comment: Using `Setup(....)` and `VerifyAll()` or only using `Verify` depends on your personal preference and also on your use case (Do you use the return value of the function you configured with `Setup`?, do you want to specify how often a function should get called with `Times`?, etc.)

Comment: Ok, I use Setup(...) and VerifyAll(). Usually functions which I am mocking are called once, so I don't use Verify(). Thanks for explaining,

Answer (score 18):

You can use the It.Is method:

```
storageManager.Setup(e => e.Add(It.Is<UserMetaData>(data => data.FirstName == "FirstName1")));
```

Answer (score 12):

Sloth's method is good and will work. You can also use callback though which is useful if you need to do any checking of the output that is more complicated.

```
 UserMetaData parameter = null;
 var storageManager = new Mock<IStorageManager>(); 
 storageManager
    .Setup(e => e.Add(It.IsAny<UserMetaData>()))
    .Callback((UserMetaData metaData) => parameter = metaData);

 Assert.That(parameter.FirstName, Is.EqualTo("FirstName1")); //If using fluent NUnit
```

The advantage of this is that, if required, you can do many more checks on the parameter rather than just checking that it is "FirstName1".

The disadvantage is that if Add is called multiple times then only the parameter passed in the last call will be checked (although you can additionally Verify that it was called once).

Dominic's answer is better than mine for your precise situation but I wanted to point out Callback for other similar situations.

Comment: thanks, that looks promising. What if there are more than one property e.g. LastName, Age, etc?

Comment: @The Light, If all these are in UserMetaData then you can check them all easily using the same method. My original answer was slightly wrong in that my Assert was checking parameter and should have been parameter.FirstName.