# Abstract Factory Unit Testing In Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Suppose I have following class called `SomeClass` as defined:

```
public SomeClass
{
    private IThingFactory _thingFactory;

    public SomeClass(IThingFactory thingFactory)
    {
        _thingFactory = thingFactory;
    }

    public IThing CreateThing(int a, int b, string c)
    {
        IThing thing = _thingFactory.MakeEmptyThing();
        thing.MakeFromFields(a, b, c);

        return thing;
    }
}
```

The spec of the `CreateThing(int a, int b, string c)` method is that it takes an int `a`, int `b`, string `c` and returns an `IThing` with the corresponding properties. (so internally maybe `new Thing(a, b, c)`)

However the implementation delegates that work to a `IThingFactory` and `Thing` populates itself.

So now I'm trying to unit test the method `CreateThing()`, but I'm not exactly sure how it should work.

Here's what I tried:

Based off of the principles of mocking dependencies, I created a `Mock<IThingFactory>` and gave it to the constructor of `SomeClass`

```
_mockThingFactory = new Mock<IThingFactory>();
someClass = new SomeClass(_mockThingFactory.Object);
```

Afterwards, I called the method under test

```
IThing thing = _someClass.CreateThing(It.IsAny<int>(), 
    It.IsAny<int>(), 
    It.IsAny<string>>());
```

And to assert, I'm not sure. Should I verify that `MakeEmptyThing()` was called? What do I do with `thing.MakeFromFields(a, b, c);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at results of the method under test. In this case result is "factory constructed object and particular method of the object is called with arguments".

To test that you can return mock object from `CreateThing` and than check if `MakeFromFields` on it called with expected parameters (i.e. [Using Moq, How to setup a method call with an input parameter as an object with expected property values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879260/using-moq-how-to-setup-a-method-call-with-an-input-parameter-as-an-object-with)).

```
var mockThing = new Mock<IThing>();
_mockThingFactory.Setup(f=> f.MakeEmptyThing()).Returns(mockThing.Object);

classUnderTest =  new SomeClass(_mockThingFactory.Object);  
classUnderTest.CreateThing(1,2,3);
mockThing.Verify(....)
```

Note that it may be better to move `MakeFromFields` to factory. Also consider using existing DI framework (like Unity) to deal with all object creation.

Comment: Does that mean that I have to mock `MakeFromFields()` as well?

Comment: @Rhs I don't think you need to mock `MakeFromFields` it. Just make sure it got called as shown in linked post.